# Avoiding extra line breaks in the ckeditor source

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I hope I'm asking this in an appropriate community.

I am a long-term fckeditor user and am biting the bullet and replacing the fckeditor with the ckeditor now. It was surprisingly easy to install and get to basically work!

I did run into one issue right away though, and I'm hoping somebody here can give me a pointer into what I can do.

The problem is extra line breaks appearing.

The first screenshot attached is what the editor looks like at my site when editing.
[image]

The 2nd screenshot attached shows  what the result looks like when viewed after posting (you can see all  extra line breaks.

[image]

The cause - if I look at the source (3rd screenshot) appears to be extra lines in the source around the ul tags.Or maybe they are around the p tags. I'm not sure.

[image]

In fact, if I edit it in "source" mode and delete the extra lines and resubmit the end result looks fine.

I was wondering what the best practice might be to avoid those extra line breaks. I modified my settings to add this:

```
        CKEDITOR.replace( '%% whichField %%', {
            on: {
                instanceReady: function( ev ) {
                    // Output paragraphs as <p>Text</p>.
                    this.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p', {
                        indent: false,
                        breakBeforeOpen: false,
                        breakAfterOpen: false,
                        breakBeforeClose: false,
                        breakAfterClose: false
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

That helped somewhat, but I'm still seeing extra blank lines in the SOURCE depending on input. I was wondering if there was a general all-around solution for this. Like instead of specifying 'p' in the above setting, can I specify something more general? Or is there a better practice to handle this kind of "extra line breaks" issue?

Thanks,

doug

Comment: I don't think the blank lines around the ul are the real problem, since html doesn't recognize new lines. That is what the <br> tag is for. How are you outputting the data from the editor? Are you using php or another backend, or are you using javascript to append it to the body?

Comment: The ckeditor textarea is part of a form. When it gets submitted, the contents of the textarea are sent to my server where they are stored in the database as is. When displayed, the contents of the database are read and shown. If I manually enter SOURCE mode in the editor and delete those blank lines everything is ok. Whatever is happening during display from the database though, it would be helpful if I could just have the ckeditor not add those extra blank lines. I don't see why they are there. So I am wondering if there is a way of not having the ckeditor put them into the source. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing between HTML elements should not make any difference as long as you don't process this code later with functions like [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), which replaces new line characters with `<BR>`.

My guess is that you have there plenty of `<BR>` tags that CKEditor did not produce, but that were done by a function similar to the one described above.

In order to stop CKEditor from producing new line characters, so that you did not have any new line characters to replace, check the [HTML Output Formatting](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/htmlformatting.html) sample for an inspiration. In the "Get Sample Source Code" section at the bottom click the first link. You will find there a code that does a bit of magic to find all elements for which to set writer rules, set `false` instead of `true` everywhere and that should do the trick:

```
for ( var e in CKEDITOR.tools.extend( {}, dtd.$nonBodyContent, dtd.$block, dtd.$listItem, dtd.$tableContent ) ) {
    this.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( e, {
        indent: false,
        breakBeforeOpen: false,
        breakAfterOpen: false,
        breakBeforeClose: false,
        breakAfterClose: false
    });
}
```

If I were you I'd rather do some smart detection whether a new line character is inside HTML tags or not before changing it into `<BR>`, to keep the HTML source code nice. You might want to check https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_linebreaks for an inspiration (I'm not the author of that module).

Comment: Yes, logically speaking what you say makes sense, since HTML ignores line spacing. So the actual displayed HTML for a message with extra line breaks contains `<br>` tags. In this example the signature is not cleaned up in SOURCE mode and a snippet looks like `<br><br><p>doug</p>` on the displayed page. So you are correct. That feature is there in case people don't use the ckeditor (e.g. their browser doesn't support it) otherwise they can't enter line breaks. Still, if ckeditor would not enter extra line breaks it would solve everything! Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Check http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/htmlformatting.html for an inspiration. In the "Get Sample Source Code" section at the bottom click the first link. You will find there a code that does a bit of magic to find all elements for which to set writer rules:  `for ( var e in CKEDITOR.tools.extend( {}, dtd.$nonBodyContent, dtd.$block, dtd.$listItem, dtd.$tableContent ) ) {`.

Comment: Sorry to be so long in replying. Thanks! That example is just what I needed. It not only works perfectly in suppressing the extra linebreaks I don't want, it has given me lots of clues for proceeding. If you want to post that as the answer I would be happy to mark it as answered.

Comment: In particular, all I did with that example was change the true values to false and comment out the line which forces ckeditor to open in source mode. I may fiddle with the true/false settings to get visually more legible source code while still not interfering with the linebreaks.

Comment: Actually, if I leave the breakBeforeOpen true and the others break options false then code comes out perfectly clean, nicely indented, linebreaks to make the code legible, but no extraneous linebreaks to interfere with my server's interpretation of extra linebreaks. Thanks again.